# PHP Error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm attempting to write a registration script for my website. All this script does is take user input from the page, and sends it to MySQL. I'm using PDO as it's supposed to be more secure, but I can't find the syntax error.

signup3.inc.php

```
<?php
// create a db connection

//initializing variables <br/><br/>
$FirstName = "";<br/>
$LastName = "";<br/>
$userName = "";<br/>
$userEmail = "";<br/>
$cUserEmail = "";<br/>
$password = "";<br/>
$cPassword = "";<br/>
$userAddress = "";<br/>
$userAddress2 = "";<br/>
$userZip = "";<br/>
$userCity = "";<br/>
$userState = "";<br/>
$userPhone = "";<br/>
$userID = "";<br/>
$today = date("r");<br/>

//defining variables

if(isset($_POST['FirstName'])){$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];}; <br/>
if(isset($_POST['LastName'])){$LastName= $_POST['LastName'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['userName'])){$userName = $_POST['userName'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['userEmail'])){$UserEmail =  $_POST['userEmail'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['cUserEmail'])){$cUserEmail =  $_POST['cUserEmail'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['password'])){$password = $_POST['password'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['cPassword'])){$cPassword = $_POST['cPassword'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['userAddress'])){$userAddress =  $_POST['userAddress'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['userAddress2'])){$userAddress2 =  $_POST['userAddress2'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['userZip'])){$userZip =  $_POST['userZip'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['userCity'])){$userCity =  $_POST['userCity'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['userState'])){$userState = $_POST['userState'];};<br/>
if(isset($_POST['userPhone'])){$userPhone =  $_POST['userPhone'];};<br/>

$query = "INSERT INTO userprofile (userFirstName, userLastName, userCity, userState, userZip, userRegDate, userPhone, userAddress, userAddress2, userEmail, userName) <br/>
VALUES ($FirstName,$LastName,$userCity,$userState,$userZip,$today,$userPhone,$userAddress,$userAddress2,$userEmail,$userName)";


$connect->exec($query);

echo "<script> alert('Account successfully created!'); window.location='index.html'</script>";
```

Comment: It would be more secure if it was using prepared statements. Also, you appear to have a '<br>' tag in the query.

Comment: Do you honestly have a <br/> tag in your SQL?

Comment: That <br/> tag will cause the error for sure. It would help if you posted the complete error that you are getting too.

Comment: Sorry, I put them there because I tried formatting my code in html for stackoverflow. There aren't actual <br /> tags in my code.